# Powershell question: is it possible to get directory path from the environment variables?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

Edit 1:

Let me re-iterate my question as I was asking the question in a wrong way and was misunderstood.

If I want to use a directory path in my powershell script, how can I use it using the $env: variable?

For example, I want my script to go to "E:\Temp\Test"

How can I go to "E:\Temp\Test" using $env: variable?

Note: The path "E:\Temp\Test" does exist in the environment variables.

I am new to IT and Powershell, so would appreciate basic terminology in the responses. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please posts the error messages _in full_ along with the code that produced it!

Comment: Do you need a way to find out where the script is executing so you can access files relative to it?  If so, here's that:
    `$ScriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.InvocationName;
    if (!$ScriptPath) { $ScriptPath = (Get-Location).Path };`

Comment: Hello all, thank you for the responses, I have had re-iterated my question as I had asked it the wrong way.

Comment: What variable? If (say) `TEMP` is set to `E:\Temp`, you can get the desired path with `${env:TEMP}\Test`, but it's not clear this is what you're after.

Comment: This is what I was looking for Jeroen, this has worked in my script. I am now able to get the path I needed, thank you.